# Right Hand Limit of function consisting of inverse trignometric functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to evaluate

$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin^{-1}(1 - \{x\}) \times \cos^{-1}(1 - \{x\})}{\sqrt{2\{x\}}\times(1 - \{x\})}
$$

where $\{x\}$ represents the [fractional part of the number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part).

Clearly, for this problem $\{x\} = x$. We can also split up the limit into two parts

$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin^{-1}(1 - x)}{1 -x}\times \lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\cos^{-1}(1 - x)}{\sqrt{2x}}
$$

The limit on the left is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which we get upon substituing the $x$ for a zero. The limit on the right is where I'm struggling.

I'm looking for a way to evaluate the limit on the right and/or a different way to approach this problem altogether.

Comment: I think you meant ```x - floor(x)```

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Yeah, my bad. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use L'Hopital:$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\cos^{-1}(1-x)}{\sqrt{2x}}=\sqrt2\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}=1$$

---

You can keep $\cos^{-1}(1-x)=m$. Then $\cos m=1-x$,$$\lim_{m\to0^+}\frac{m}{\sqrt{2(1-\cos m)}}=\lim_{m\to0^+}\frac{m}{\sqrt{4\sin^2(m/2)}}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

For the limit on right convert the $\cos^{-1}$ to $\sin^{-1}$ to get
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\dfrac{\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2})}{\sqrt{2}x}$$

which can be evaluated easily

Comment: The limit on the right should become $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2})}{\sqrt{2x}}$$, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'll edit that thanks

Answer (score 0):

For $\lim_{x \to 0^+}$ we write $x=1+h, h>0$
then
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin^{-1}(1 - \{x\}) \times \cos^{-1}(1 - \{x\})}{\sqrt{2\{x\}}\times(1 - \{x\})}$$
$$ L=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin^{-1}(1-h) \cos^{-1}(1-h)}{\sqrt{2h} (1-h)}$$
$$L=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin^{-1}(1-h)}{(1-h)} \frac{\cos^{-1}(1-h)}{\sqrt{2h}}$$
$$L=\frac{\pi}{2} \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\cos^{-1}(1-h)}{\sqrt{2h}}$$
Use L=Hosp. now
$$L=\frac{\pi}{2} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2/\sqrt{1-(1-h)^2}~\sqrt{h}}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Use $(1-h)^2\to 1-2h$, then
$$L=\frac{\pi}{2} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2\sqrt{h}}{2\sqrt{h}}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$